# How to get rid of this Error Generating Code Coverage in Xcode 9.4

Tags: code-coverage, xcode-ui-testing, xcode9.4

I continuously see this pop up "Error Generating Code Coverage " when I try to run my UI Tests and this is followed by another error bundle identifier missing. I have enable code coverage in test scheme. I am really looking forward to run my UI Tests without this blocking error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this temporarrily though not sure if it is proper solution.

Every time I need to clean project

Xcode -> Preferences -> Derived data(Delete this folder)

Build the project and then run the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Apple had an issue which was filed under open radar for Xcode 9 and this got resolved with XCode 10

One potential solution would be :

- Move to Xcode 10 and enable code coverage in Build Settings.
- Also, in your test scheme by going into the Test action and check the
  "Enable the Code Coverage checkbox" to gather coverage data ( As you see in the image in the question )

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error when using simulator with iOS < 10. So using later iOS version simulators solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar issue with the next error log:

> 14:35:45.129 Xcode[83419:1712361] _finishWithError:Error
>   Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch session
>   expired before checking in." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launch
>   session expired before checking in.}

Resolved it by adding missed frameworks to the unit tests target:

- drag the built frameworks to the Link Binaries build phase of the tests target.
- in the Test target under the Build Settings tab, add @loader_path/Frameworks to the Runpath Search Paths if it isn't already present.
- make sure dependencies are present in a test bundle. Create a new Copy Files build phase with the Frameworks destination, then add the framework reference there as well.